# send the custom information to user with asmack in android

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am building chat application with asmack in android where in I want to send some notification to other user.

I mean to say, like how we exchange the data in xml, json etc in web service communications.

So I looked into many posts which says use IQ, PlayListListener etc.. But I am not getting which one I have to start digging and write code.

Can someone tell me which one suits best for my requirement of exchanging the data b/w android clients.

TIA.

Comment: Use a message stanza if you don't care about acks, use IQ if you care about the receiving entity ack'ing stanza.

Comment: I found a [link](https://vanity-igniterealtime.jiveon.com/docs/DOC-2702) which explains custom IQ implementation. is BOT in it means the other side client? is there any blog which explains with eg..